# Pine script input menu

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm making an indicator with a built in menu with long and short signals ( crossover, crossunder)
how do i use different values for the crossover and crossunder for each crypto pair to change long and short signal for each coin when selected from the menu.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `input.symbol()` so that the user can choose any ticker id, or use `input.string()` and provide some pre-defined ticker ids.

Then do a string comparison (e.g. if the ticker is BTC) and use whatever values you want to use for the `crossover()` and `crossunder()`.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

ticker_symbol = input.symbol("", "Symbol")
ticker_str = input.string("BTC", "Ticker", ["BTC", "ETH", "XRP"])
plot(close)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i already added the symbols as shown in the image using input.string. i can't however use the different crossover and crossunder values for each symbol

Comment: What is the problem? Is it getting data from those other tickers?